# Why does getElementById method work with a single variable but not with two concatenated variables?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have these two variables (email and name), and their sum (emailName):

```
var email = 'email_address';
var name = 'your_name';
var emailName = email + name;
```

When I use the email or name variable in getElementById, it works perfectly. But when it's emailName, it doesn't. Why?

```
button_click = function() {
    window.parent.postMessage(document.getElementById(emailName).value, "*");
}
```

Comment: Do you have an element with `id="email_addressyour_name"`?

Comment: @Teemu just checked, I don't!

Comment: Wouldn't it be frightend, if `gEBI` would find a non-existing element? The method doesn't do any magic with the passed argument, it just tries to find an element having the exact id you passed to it.

Comment: @Teemu yes, you're right. I just tried to use .setAttribute and .id but it doesn't seem to work yet :/ Maybe I'm doing some detail wrong, I'll try again. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you should describe your problem better, we've actually no clue what do you want to send as a message. I think you want the values of `#email_address` and `#your_name` elements, but @isherwood seems to disagree. Please add more details into your question.

Comment: @Teemu I did a form and I wanted to embed in my website using HTML iframe, as I used Wix, the only way to storage data from the form is to send with postMessage! It works just fine, but I can only send one information (either the email or the name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately you cannot use a shortcut like the one you are trying to do. you will have to do something like this:

```js
button_click = function() {
var email = 'email_address';
var name = 'your_name';
  console.log(document.getElementById(name).innerHTML+document.getElementById(email).innerHTML, "*");
}
button_click();
```

```html
<div id='email_address'>
email adress
</div>
<div id='your_name'>
your name
</div>
```

or, if you are able to, use a classname.

Comment: I don't think you've understood the problem. There's no mention of getting string values from inside elements.

Comment: I still had to use the .postMessage as I'm connecting Wix dataset with HTML iframe, but besides that it was it! HTML was already assigned.Thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score -1):

You have to put the same ID to both elements. And if you want to get more elements (like buttons, paragraphs or anything) at the same time you should use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("the class name that you have put to both objects");
```

or

```
document.getElementsByName("the name that you have put to both objects");
```

Remember that first you have to assign the ID/class/name to the element like below here:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp

More documentation:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

Comment: You should suggest modern approach like querySelectorAll....

Comment: That is still ok, everyone still suggests that. And it's fine if you are learning the basics @epascarello

Comment: @AdrianoSordi thank you!! I assigned them and I was having trouble in working with two different ids, but I found a way with the other answer with the plus '+' sign. But thank you so much for helping, I'm new here and I appreciate it!